# Disable merge access but have approve access

Tags: github

I want to know if there is a way that a collaborator has only code-review approve access but not merge access in GitHub i.e. if the codeowner user has submitted a PR and the setting approval required is enabled as well as the setting Require review from code owners is enabled and a collaborator has approved the PR review, but the merge button is disabled and only the admin of the repository or code owner of the file can merge the PR.

I am aware that this can be achieved with the CODEOWNERS file, but I am unable to set it up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.